# #Jquery : is it possible to pass input value without using id,class,name?

Tags: php, jquery

In one of the company while giving interview as a PHP Developer.

> He asked me, How to pass variable in jQuery without using name
>   attribute , id and class??

Comment: yes, pretty possible...

Comment: We can set our own attribute to that element.

Comment: yes you can... using value, element name itself and so on..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can mention the element itself.

For example:

```
<p>This is a paragraph</p>

$("p").text("Test message");  // This will select all p tags.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,there are many selectors in jquery read [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

**EXAMPLE**

```
$('input[type="text"]').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your interviewer wanted to know about [attribute selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) from you:

Example:

```
$( "input[value='Foo Bar']" ) //select the input which value is 'Foo Bar'
```